# DateTime with milliseconds in C#

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a `Int64` variable (eg : 637383629352337674). I have to use this variable to create a `DateTime` object which uses this number.
So I used the following constructor to create the DateTime object :

```
public DateTime (long ticks);
```

But I observed that I am not able to get the milliseconds printed when I use the `ToString()` method of `DateTime` class.

It would be possible to get the millisecinds printed with `DateTimeOffset` being concatenated with the `ToString()` of DateTime object, but I don't want to do that.

How can I get a DateTime object with milliseconds ?

Comment: your code `new DateTime(637383629352337674).Millisecond` returns 233... so you are ... misleading in your post. Please [edit] to clarify what you actually need.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/how-to-display-milliseconds-in-date-and-time-values

Answer (score 4):

Your datetime has milliseconds, just make sure you include them in the ToString format specifier (the default format string doesn't include milliseconds):

```
.ToString("HH:mm:ss.ffffff")
```

[see example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/mdzmCm)

For more info on date time format strings, see [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings)

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking about including the milliseconds when converting the `DateTime` to a `String`, google `DateTime format string`. First hit is https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/date-and-time-format-in-c-sharp-programming1

You can include the milliseconds like this:
`myDate.ToString("HH:mm:ss.fff");`

You can use up to seven "f"s there.